# Specifying Spark Schema won't show correct display results

Tags: python-3.x, azure-databricks, pyspark

I am specifying the schema for my spark code but the results all return NULL. However, when I inferSchema=True, header=True I get the correct results.

For example my schema is as follows:

```
myschema = StructType([StructField("event_ts", IntegerType(), True)
                       ,StructField("sdk_ts", IntegerType(), True)
                       ,StructField("device_id", StringType(), True)
                       ,StructField("latitude", DoubleType(), True)
                       ,StructField("longitude", DoubleType(), True)
                       ,StructField("country", StringType(), True)])
```

When I apply the schema to read in file as a dataframe as follows:

```
testzip = spark.read.csv("adl://mylake.azuredatalakestore.net/filepath/01/000000000000.csv.gz",schema=myschema)
```

I get the following results all showing NULL

[image]

However, when I read in the data with inferSchema=True, header=True as follows, I get the correct result i.e no NULLs

```
testzip = spark.read.csv("adl://mylake.azuredatalakestore.net/filepath/01/000000000000.csv.gz",inferSchema=True,header=True)
```

I'm certain I'm missing something very obvious, but just can't see it.

Comment: try spark.read.load('adl://mylake.azuredatalakestore.net/filepath/01/000000000000.csv.gz', format="csv", header="true", sep=',', schema=customSchema);

Comment: also share the file with sample records

Comment: @dassum, thanks for responding. Unfortunately, your suggestion produced the same NULL report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The records are failing to match the schema. The default action here is for spark to output the results to a column called _corrupt_record (the default mode is called Permissive) which if you add to a select you will see you data.

To resolve I would change each data type in you schema to StringType(). It should now give you results. Then change them back one at a time to work out which conversion is failing. It’s probably the doubletype. Maybe import as string and then convert.

More on permissive mode here. https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html

Comment: Hi Simon, changing the data types all to StringType() produced results as you suggested. I will change them back one at a time to find out one is failing

Comment: Simon, you were correct. The problem failed at DoubleType. I also needed to add header=True